# What's the exact reason a pod-template-hash is added to the name of the replicaset when a deployment is created?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, replicaset

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment mentions that a `deployment` creates a `replicaSet` but appends a `pod-template-hash` to the name of the `replicaSet` and also adds `pod-template-hash` as `replicaSet`'s label.

my best guess is that `deployment` creates multiple `replicaSets` and this hash ensures that the replicas do not overlap. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6):

Correct, the documentation states this really well:

> The `pod-template-hash` label is added by the Deployment controller to
> every ReplicaSet that a Deployment creates or adopts.
>
> This label ensures that child ReplicaSets of a Deployment do not
> overlap. It is generated by hashing the `PodTemplate` of the ReplicaSet
> and using the resulting hash as the label value that is added to the
> ReplicaSet selector, Pod template labels, and in any existing Pods
> that the ReplicaSet might have.

This is necessary for a bunch of different reasons:

- When you apply a new version of a Deployment, depending on how the deployment is configured and on probes, the previous Pod / Pods could stay up until the new one / ones is not Running and Ready and only then is gracefully terminated. So it may happens that Pods of different `ReplicaSet` (previous and current) run at the same time.
- Deployment History is available to be consulted and you may also want to rollback to an older revision, should the current one stops behaving correctly (for example you changed the image that needs to be used and it jsut crash in error). Each revision has its own ReplicaSet ready to be scaled up or down as necessary as explained in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#checking-rollout-history-of-a-deployment)

Comment: still it s not clear why they say "This label ensures that child ReplicaSets of a Deployment do not overlap". they can not overlap. every rs and every pod of rs have  "ownerReferences" section that states  who is the owner of the pod of rs.  "ownerReferences" says who is the owner of the object. in my opinion "pod-template-hash" absolutely not  necessary.

Comment: Without this hash, when a Deployment specs are updated and a new ReplicaSet needs to be created, how would it be distinguished from the previous one? I think this is not a matter of overlapping ownership of objects, it is more of a matter of overlapping specs. When a Deployment is changed, the previous ReplicaSet needs to remain in the history.

Comment: when deployment creates  new RS  it adds some hash in the end of the NAME of rs. so two rs have different names. from this point of view we can distinguish them without any problem, also every rs have uuid.  deployment can track rs names or uuid  in its history. we dont need adiitional labels to distinguish one rs from another.  what am i missing ?

Comment: `pod-template-hash` as a label is very useful for propagating this info into the pod using the Downward API. For example, when you want the application to introspect its membership with regards to the replica set it's running in. Without the label, the only other way to do this would be to extract the hash from the pod's name, which would be fragile and implementation-dependent. You don't need this label until you do, @Alex :)